# Finding Missing values but not of NAN format

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am learning pandas for Data Science. I have come across how to find missing values using np.nan if the missing values are nan type. But what if the missing values are written as #### or ** then how to find those rows? suppose i dont know what type of symbols are inserted, it may be * or  # etc, then how should i approach?

Do i need to consult with the person who is collecting the data or run a loop?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) of your dataset? What are the non missing values? numbers?

Comment: In order for a cell to contain "####" or "**", it has to be a string column, where NaNs do not apply.  Those would not be missing values.  They are valid string values.  You need to understand how those are expected to be processed.

Comment: @Tim you **can** have NaNs in a string/object column to denote missing values.

Comment: I second the need for an MRE. If you're looking at the data in Excel, [a bunch of hash signs `#` usually means the cell isn't wide enough to show the cell contents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-error-bf801d0a-2a6e-44bd-a70e-0f780ae8f11e). Apparently Lotus 123 does the same thing but with stars `*`. If that's the case then this is a non-issue WRT Pandas.

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

If the missing values in your dataset are represented by various symbols such as #### or **, and you don't have a fixed pattern to identify them, you might need to adopt a flexible approach to handle these cases. you can Look for common patterns among the missing values. then you can use these patterns to identify missing values. Or if possible consult the person who collected the data They might provide insights into how missing values are represented in the dataset ,if the dataset is not too large you can iterate through the data and manually inspect rows to identify the patterns used for missing values try this using pandas and regular expressions so we can  identify rows with missing values and feel free to modify it to fit you need

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'Column1': ['123', '456', '####', '789', '**', '101112']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define patterns to identify missing values
missing_patterns = ['####', '**']

# Identify rows with missing values
missing_rows = df.apply(lambda row: any(pattern in str(row) for pattern in missing_patterns), axis=1)

# Display rows with missing values
print(df[missing_rows])
```

**Cleaning Data**

```
def strip_missing_values(value):
    # Replace common missing value patterns
    if '####' in str(value) or '**' in str(value):
        return np.nan
    else:
        return value

# Apply the cleaning function to the DataFrame
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(strip_missing_values)
```

Hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a string column, you can create a list of possible values and then check whether any values in the dataframe are in that list using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html). For example, using this sample data:

```py
data = {
  'Column1': [np.nan, '123', '456', '####', '789', '**', '101112'],
  'Column2': [456, '**', '888', np.nan, '999', '####', '2442']
}
missing = [np.nan, '####', '**']

# find any values which are "missing"; output is a df of boolean values matching the form of the input
df.isin(missing)
#    Column1  Column2
# 0     True    False
# 1    False     True
# 2    False    False
# 3     True     True
# 4    False    False
# 5     True     True
# 6    False    False

# find any columns with missing values; output is a Series indexed by column names
df.isin(missing).any(axis=0)
# Column1    True
# Column2    True
# dtype: bool

# find any rows with missing values; output is a Series with the same row indexes as the df
df.isin(missing).any(axis=1)
# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2    False
# 3     True
# 4    False
# 5     True
# 6    False
# dtype: bool

# remove rows with missing values from df
df = df[~df.isin(missing).any(axis=1)]
#   Column1 Column2
# 2     456     888
# 4     789     999
# 6  101112    2442
```